# Pine tree leaves using Sapling; giving stylized look

Tags: sapling-addon

Trying to make a stylized pine tree (like in Among Trees Game)
[image]

I can't figure out how to make leaves like these; so one falling on each side.
[image]

Using the sapling plugin; is there a way to make it so ?
Pulling out my hairs here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it without addon, you need to create some flat branches, like that (I copied but of course do your own):

[image]

Rotate, mirror:

[image]

Duplicate, rotate, etc:

[image]

Comment: Of course i can manually do it; i thought there was a way to make use of the sapling plugin to 'automate' the process, maybe ?

Comment: oops you're right I lost your initial question, I've edited, I don't know this addon